# Node.js modules for unit testing

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, node.js, buster.js

Suppose I have a web application, which uses jQuery for Ajax and UI. Now I would like to add unit-tests to it. I would like the unit-tests to run in a single process without launching browsers and separate web servers and I hope it is doable with the Node.js and the following Node.js modules:

- `buster.js`
- jQuery Node.js module
- jsdom Node.js module

Am I missing something? Is there any example of such unit tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can write your test routines with `assert`, but I'd like to recommend using unit-testing frameworks - more specifically, [nodeunit](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit/). There's [a neat article](http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/unit_testing_in_node_js) describing how to use this module to simplify unit testing.

And may I say there's actually a bunch of threads here with (ahem...) the same question - for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254025/node-js-unit-testing), with plenty of choices. )

Answer (score 2):

Try the "assert" module. It's included in standard Node.js, and you can do something like:

```
var assert = require('assert');
assert.ok(true, 'test fails');
```