# How to test client-side code with NodeUnit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, node.js, client-side

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169335/node-js-modules-for-unit-testing).

Suppose I am writing the `calculate.js` source file with a `calculate` function to use it in my client-side code:

```
function calculate(num) {
    return num * 2;
}
```

Now I would like to test it.

I am using `nodeunit` as described in [this article](http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/unit_testing_in_node_js) and *export* the `calculate` function (so that tests can invoke it).

```
function calculate(num) {
    return num * 2;
}

exports.calculate = calculate // Node.js stuff. It won't run in a browser!
```

The `nodeunit` tests run OK, but I cannot use `calculate.js` in my web application any longer since it uses `exports`.

Now it looks like a catch. Can I fix this problem?

Comment: I think you can accomplish by reading my answer => http://stackoverflow.com/a/11191904/11926

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a non-Node.js testing framework like jasminebdd or jstestdriver.

Comment: Thanks. I still want to run my tests by `node` though. AFAIR `jstestdriver` is Java so I would like to avoid it. Can I make `node` run `jamsine`?

Comment: have a read of this maybe to load none node js into node js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171213/load-vanilla-javascript-libraries-into-node-js

Comment: Thanks. Maybe the solution is just to make "node module wrappers".

Comment: just wondering why u need to run it via node ? when its just simple js

Comment: Node just looks like a convenient tool to run java script in command line. So I am thinking about using it for unit-testing. Maybe it is my mistake though.

Answer (score 2):

[Running tests in the browser](https://github.com/caolan/nodeunit#running-tests-in-the-browser)

> If you wish to use a CommonJS format for your test suites (using
> exports), it is up to you to define the CommonJS tools for the
> browser. There are a number of alternatives and its important it fits
> with your existing code, which is why nodeunit does not currently
> provide this out of the box.

I think you should have a look at Browserify to accomplish this.

[Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)

> Make Node.js-style require() work in the browser with a server-side build
> step, as if by magic!

[Mocha](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha)

> Mocha is a simple, flexible, fun JavaScript test framework for Node.js
> and the browser.

I think you should have a look at Mocha created by TJ (Express.js' author) which I like very much (better than nodeunit which I used in the past). With Mocha you can easily do code coverage, watch-mode, notifications and as a big plus Mocha is more maintained.

Answer (score 2):

[Karma runner](http://karma-runner.github.io/) has a [nodeunit adapter](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-nodeunit) to run nodeunit tests in browsers and PhantomJS. Here's an example [test entrypoint](https://github.com/hurrymaplelad/browser-forms/blob/master/test/test.js) and [Gruntfile](https://github.com/hurrymaplelad/browser-forms/blob/master/Gruntfile.js) using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) to run tests written in [CommonJS modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) (exports).

Answer (score 2):

[nodeunit-browser-tap](https://github.com/hurrymaplelad/nodeunit-browser-tap) + [Testling](http://ci.testling.com/) is another option if you're set on nodeunit.

- The [Testling npm package](https://npmjs.org/package/testling) gets you command line output for tests run in a local browser.
- [Testling.com](http://ci.testling.com/) gets you free cross browser CI if you host on GitHub.
- The browser-tap wrapper gets you nodeunit output that Testling understands.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually test isolated jQuery logic within nodeunit itself. For example, here is some tests I wrote for my datepicker library:

```
/* jshint evil:true */
/* global module, require, DatePair */

var fs = require('fs');
// Some of the plugins use a jQuery variable instead of $
var jQuery = require('jquery');
var $ = jQuery;

// Recreate window and document
var window = { jQuery: jQuery };
var document = window;

// The file is included here:
eval(fs.readFileSync('../lib/js/jquery/plugins/jquery.cookie.js') + '');
eval(fs.readFileSync('../lib/js/jquery.timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js') + '');
eval(fs.readFileSync('../lib/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-datepicker.js') + '');
eval(fs.readFileSync('../homepage/js/datepair.js') + '');

// Initialize DatePair Object
var datePair = DatePair(new Date(), {
    dateStart: $('<input type="text" autocomplete="off">'),
    dateEnd: $('<input type="text" autocomplete="off">'),
    timeStart: $('<input type="text" autocomplete="off">'),
    timeEnd: $('<input type="text" autocomplete="off">')
});

module.exports = {
    'Time Delta Var Is 1 hour' : function (test) {
        test.equal(datePair.getTimeDelta(), 3600);
        test.done();
    },
    'Change Date And Check For 1 Hour Difference' : function (test) {
        datePair.startTime.val("10:00pm").change();
        test.equal(datePair.endTime.val(), "11:00pm");
        test.done();
    },
    'Make End Date Move Up One Day' : function (test) {
        var expectedEndDates = [1];
        datePair.startTime.val("11:00pm").change();
        expectedEndDates.push(parseInt(datePair.startDate.val().split("/")[1], 10) + 1);

        test.ok($.inArray(parseInt(datePair.endDate.val().split("/")[1], 10), expectedEndDates) !== -1);
        test.equal(datePair.endTime.val(), "12:00am");
        test.done();
    },
    'Change To 11:30pm Of Previous Day' : function (test) {
        // Move startTime 1 Day Forward
        datePair.startTime.val("11:00pm").change();
        // Move EndDate 1 Day Backwards
        datePair.endTime.val("11:30pm").change();

        test.equal(datePair.endDate.val(), datePair.startDate.val());
        test.done();
    }
}
```

See the full code + library here: https://github.com/keithhackbarth/jquery-datetime-picker